# View file cannot be found when creating new class

Tags: add-on-development

**Edit**

I have two separate add-ons in play here with EE 3.5.3

- addons/project/ext.project.php
- addons/project_mailer/mod.project_mailer.php
- addons/project_mailer/views/mail_template.php

---

I've got an extension set up that includes a module file, so that I can call a function from it later on (see below).

```
<?php
/**
 * File: ext.project.php
 **/

if ( ! class_exists( 'Project_mailer' ) )
{
    require_once( PATH_THIRD . 'project_mailer/mod.project_mailer.php' );
}

// Code and stuff

$mailer = new Project_mailer();
$mailer->send_mail_update( $entry_id, $channel_id );
?>
```

This is all working fine and the function is called however when I try to load a view from it I'm getting an error: `Unable to load the requested file: mail_template.php`

My assumption is that because I'm creating a new instance of the class it's looking for the view file relative to my extension rather than the module? (Correct me if I'm wrong on that though)

I've attached a copy of the code within the `send_mail_update` function below. I tried to use the commented out line instead however the same error appears but with the full path included.

```
<?php
/**
 * File: mod.project_mailer.php
 **/

public function send_mail_update( $entry_id, $channel_id )
{
    // Code and stuff

    return ee()->load->view( 'mail_template', $data, TRUE );
    //ee()->load->view( PATH_THIRD . 'project_mailer/views/mail_template', $data, TRUE );

}
```

Is there any way to get the view to show correctly in my current set up?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this all part of the same addon? EE version? Whats the folder structure for this look like?

Comment: Apologies, I've added a bit more information to the question. There are two addons; one extension (1st block of code) and a module (2nd block) and the site is running EE 3.5.3.

Comment: My intuition tells me that I would combine these together. You can have a module and extension in the same addon. Managing dependencies across separate addons doesn't seem like a lot of fun.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I reckon you're right, it makes sense really.